# Azure function knowing domain

Tags: azure-functions

I have a couple of azure functions that are HTTP triggered and I want to do some quick tests in this service. It will be super helpful if there is a way to know the domain where the request to azure functions have been made from.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want the information about the connection, you can access it via the `HttpRequest` parameter that is passed in an HTTP triggered function.

Try the following, let me know if this gives you all the information you need:

```
ConnectionInfo httpContextConnection = req.HttpContext.Connection;
IPAddress remoteIpAddress = httpContextConnection.RemoteIpAddress;
```

Note, that this will only get the client IP address, not the domain.
I'm not aware of a method to get the domain. Especially since most of the clients that will access your functions, probably won't have one at all.

Comment: You're right getting the domain is not possible as far as HttpRequest is using IPs and as you said most of the clients won't have a domain. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `HttpRequestMessage` for the incoming request, i think it can be done like this

```
var context = (DefaultHttpContext) req.Properties["HttpContext"];
var Host = context.Request.Host;
```

**EDIT** : Adding sample output

[image]